# Python. Why I cannot get a candlestick?

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I have a trouble while writing code in Python. The task is to draw candlestick bars using financial tick data. First of all, I made four new columns from 'Bid' "Ask" to "Open", "High", "Low", "Close" (because candlestick requires such columns).
Okay, now I fixed some things and now I'm stuck with new problems. The sentence below is one of lots of various errors which I don't understand:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert -1 to a date. This often happens if non-datetime 
values are passed to an axis that expects datetime objects.
```

When I try to print especially Date_Time, I get this:

```
Date_Time
2016-05-02 00:00:00   NaN
2016-05-02 00:10:00   NaN
2016-05-02 00:20:00   NaN
2016-05-02 00:30:00   NaN
2016-05-02 00:40:00   NaN
Freq: 10T, Name: Date_Time, dtype: float64
```

I have no idea how I came to NaN.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as dates
data_pd = pd.read_csv('EURUSD-2016-05.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'])
data_pd.head()
format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
data_pd['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_pd['Date_Time'], format = format)
data_pd = data_pd.set_index(data_pd['Date_Time'])
data_pd = data_pd.drop(columns=['Symbol'])

data_ask = data_pd['Ask'].resample('10Min').ohlc()

data_ask = data_ask.reindex(columns= ['Date_Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])

ohlc = data_ask[['Date_Time','open','high','low','close']]
f1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=.6, colorup='green', colordown='red')

plt.show()
```

My data looks like:

```
EUR/USD,20160502 00:00:00.033,1.14607,1.14613
EUR/USD,20160502 00:00:00.149,1.14607,1.14613
EUR/USD,20160502 00:00:00.237,1.14607,1.1461
EUR/USD,20160502 00:00:00.332,1.14605,1.1461
```

Here's the link where you can get my data:

```
https://pepperstone.com/uk/client-resources/historical-tick-data
```

I'd be really thankful for any help. Please be kind, because I'm new to Python.

Comment: You try with `pd.read_csv('EURUSD-2016-05.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Bid', 'Ask'], index_col='Date_Time', parse_dates=True)` refer [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more details.

Comment: `data_pd = data_pd.reindex(columns= ['Data_Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])` - this line says `'Data_Time'` not `'Date_Time'`

Comment: Also you have dropped the column `Date_Time` and then referring it again.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But it doesn't help anyways :/

Comment: @GiedrėJuodzevičiūtė    Can you please update your error that you're getting ?

Comment: If you fix the typo that @asongtoruin highlighted it should make a notable difference already.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 355, in <module>
    ohlc = data_ask[['Date_Time','open','high','low','close']]
  File "-", line 2682, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "-", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "-", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['Date_Time'] not in index"

Comment: And that's after you fixed the typo (i.e. `Data_Time` instead of `Date_Time`)?

Comment: Yes. And after fixing that thing with dropped column as well.

Comment: Can you update your code with the fixes? [edit your question to do that]

Comment: @lanS I've just edited it as you asked me. Also added some new issues...

Comment: Please see my answer. In the future please tell at which line the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

When you resample `data_pd['Ask']`,

```
data_ask = data_pd['Ask'].resample('10Min').ohlc()
```

you get these columns back: `['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']` and the (resampled) time becomes the index.

As a result when you reindex,

```
data_ask.reindex(columns=['Date_Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
```

since the column `Date_Time` does not exist the reindex operation returns a column of missing values.

What might help is:

```
data_ask.reset_index()
```

This will turn the index back into a column, if that's what you need.

---

**Edit**: Based on the explanation above, calculating `ohlc` as such should work:

```
data_ask = data_pd['Ask'].resample('10Min').ohlc()
ohlc = data_ask.reset_index()
```

Comment: @lanS Could you please show me how my code should look like? At least those few important lines because I'm afraid I don't understand your suggestions correctly. For example, I didn't understand whether I need to delete this line:

    data_ask.reindex(columns=['Date_Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
or I must leave it and add the code
data_ask.reset_index() 
below?

Comment: I'll try to explain the problem: after I resample data_pd['Ask'], I get the table where Date_Time is as index and 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close' are the columns. When my code reaches the line ohlc =....., I get an error that my Date_Time is NOT in index!

Comment: So what I did was re-indexing everything and then I come to NaN values!

Comment: @GiedrėJuodzevičiūtė can you check again?